# how to schedule a SQL query to run every hour

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services

I have a DB and I want to find variance in data of current day previous hour and previous day same hour
e.g. difference between no. of rows with **23/10/2022 9-10 pm** and **22/10/2022 9-10 pm**

now my approach is

- writing sql queries for counting the difference and finding the deviation is one part of the problem
- second, running this query every hour
- third, if variance >0.3 send message

now doing 1st part is easy, I want to know how to address 2nd and 3rd part of the problem

```
select 
  (
    SELECT 
      count(*) as val1 from t1
      WHERE(YEAR=YEAR(current_date) AND MONTH=MONTH(current_date) AND DAY=Day(current_date) AND HOUR=Hour(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
  ) - (
    SELECT 
      count(*) as val2 from t2
      WHERE(YEAR=YEAR(current_date) AND MONTH=MONTH(current_date) AND DAY=Day(current_date-interval '1' day) AND HOUR=Hour(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) 
  ) as total_count;
```

Comment: You could write a lambda function that is triggered by a cloudwatch event at the interval you mentioned. The lambda can make the query and based on the result send message (via SNS or whatever).

Comment: What kind of database are you working with?

Comment: @AnthonyB. is there a way to get number of rows without using SQL query. Can we use file metadata to find number of rows??